# Dynamically created object not populated as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am trying to extract data from one object, restructure and create a new one.

Simplified example for the source object

```
var res = [{
    DateTime: '00:00',
  Number: 1,
  WeekDay: 1
},
{
    DateTime: '00:00',
  Number: 4,
  WeekDay: 1
},
{
    DateTime: '00:00',
  Number: 1,
  WeekDay: 2
},
{
    DateTime: '00:30',
  Number: 1,
  WeekDay: 2
}]
```

From here I want to create a new object where "number" is summed by
1. WeekDay
2. Half hour interval

```
var intervals = ['00:00', '00:30']
var weekdays = [1, 2]

var target = []
var intervalObj = [];
    for (i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) {
        intervalObj.push({
            interval: intervals[i],
            number: 0
        })
      }

 for (i = 0; i < weekdays.length; i++) {
 var day = i + 1;
        target.push({
                day: day,
            data: intervalObj,
        })
      }
```

And then populate the new object like this:

```
for(var row in res) {
    var dt = res[row].DateTime;
  var wd = res[row].WeekDay;
  var wdidx = weekdays.indexOf(wd)
  var dtidx = intervals.indexOf(dt)
  var num = res[row].Number;

  target[wdidx].data[dtidx].number += num;
}
```

This does not work when creating the target object like above. The summed results gets repeated for the same interval over all week days.
However, when object is statically:

```
var target = [{
  day: 1,
  data: [{
    interval: '00:00',
    number: 0
  },
  {
    interval: '00:30',
    number: 0
}]
},
{
  day: 2,
  data: [{
    interval: '00:00',
    number: 0
  },
  {
    interval: '00:30',
    number: 0
  }]
}]
```

It works as expected. I cannot figure out why.
Here is a fiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/oceansmoving/wkfL9e3o/

Comment: Anyone?........

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same array reference `intervalObj` for `data` in each instance of loop. Need to create new array for each instance

Change

```
var intervalObj = [];
for (i = 0; i < weekdays.length; i++) {
  var day = i + 1;
  target.push({
    day: day,
    data: intervalObj,
  })
}
```

To

```
//var intervalObj = [];
for (i = 0; i < weekdays.length; i++) {
  var day = i + 1;
  target.push({
    day: day,
    data: [],
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is intended. For each week day I want all half hour intervals to be repeated.

Comment: Then I'm not understanding what the specific problem is although I think you don't realize that using same array reference means changes to one will be made to all references of that array

Comment: Please see the expexted output and compare with what is being logged to console in fiddle.